# R survey package and predicted marginals for a continuous covariate

Tags: r, logistic-regression, survey, marginal-effects

I am attempting to obtain the risk/prevalence ratio for a two-unit increase in a continuous covariate, after adjusting for other covariates. However, it appears that R is treating my continuous covariate as a factor despite specifying it is numeric. I am using the `survey` package and the `svypredmeans` and `svycontrast` commands.

Here is a reproducible example. I am attempting to find the prevalence/risk ratio for a 2-unit increase in avg.ed after adjusting for awards and comp.imp. The variable avg.ed is numeric class but I've also specified again "as.numeric" in the code. However, different 2-unit increases for avg.ed yield different ratios, which makes me thing that the variable is not being treated as continuous. My code is based off this: https://gist.github.com/tslumley/2e74cd0ac12a671d2724

```
library(survey)
data(api)

#apply survey design
dstrat <- svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)
#fit model without continuous predictor of interest 
model <- svyglm(I(sch.wide=="Yes") ~ awards+comp.imp , design=dstrat, family=quasibinomial()) 
#obtain predicted marginals 
predmarg<-svypredmeans(model, ~as.numeric(avg.ed), predictat=c(0, 2, 4,6, 8,10 ))
#despite being categorized as a continuous predictor, the ratio is not the same for various 2 unit increases
#PR for 2 vs. 0: 
svycontrast(predmarg,quote(`2`/`0`))
#PR for 4 vs. 2: 
svycontrast(predmarg,quote(`4`/`2`))
#PR for 6 vs. 4: 
svycontrast(predmarg,quote(`6`/`4`))
#PR for 8 vs. 6: 
svycontrast(predmarg,quote(`8`/`6`))
#PR for 10 vs. 8: 
svycontrast(predmarg,quote(`10`/`8`))
```

Output of above (as you'll see the ratios are not the same)

```
> svycontrast(predmarg,quote(`2`/`0`))
          nlcon    SE
contrast 1.1232 0.055
> svycontrast(predmarg,quote(`4`/`2`))
          nlcon     SE
contrast 1.1282 0.0811
> svycontrast(predmarg,quote(`6`/`4`))
          nlcon     SE
contrast 1.0689 0.0144
> svycontrast(predmarg,quote(`8`/`6`))
         nlcon     SE
contrast 1.025 0.0207
> svycontrast(predmarg,quote(`10`/`8`))
          nlcon     SE
contrast 1.0078 0.0131
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not treating it as a factor. The updated model inside `svypredmeans` has just a single term for your `avg.ed` variable; it's modelled linearly as the documentation says.

You shouldn't expect those ratios to all be the same, for two reasons. First, those are ratios of *probabilities* rather than ratios of *odds*. Your model specifies odds ratios rather than probability ratios, and the ratios of odds are much more similar.

Second, the odds ratios won't be the exactly same because there's averaging.

If you have `p_i(avg.ed)` for person `i`, and to simplify notation we pretend you fitted a model with a log rather than logit link, then there's a difference between

```
sum(p_i(2)/pi_i(0))
sum(p_i(4)/pi_i(2))
```

and

```
sum(pi_2(2))/sum(pi_i(0))
sum(pi_2(4))/sum(pi_i(2))
```

The first pair are the same, because the model says `pi_i(2)/pi_i(0)` is the same as `pi_i(4)/pi_i(2)` for each `i`. The second pair aren't equal.